# Подстановка значений (да,нет) в sql запросе

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос

```sql
select 
    t1.`ID`,
    t1.`TABID`,
    t1.`NAME`,
    t3.`NAME` as device_name,
    t2.`LOGTIME`,
    ord(substr(t2.`LOGDATA`,5,1)) as dir
from
    `tc-db-main`.personal as t1
inner join 
    `tc-db-log`.logs as t2
inner join 
    `tc-db-main`.devices as t3
on
    t1.`ID` = t2.`EMPHINT`
and 
    t3.`ID` = t2.`DEVHINT`
and 
    logtime 
between 
    '2019-12-02 07:00:00' and '2019-12-02 23:00:00'
order by `NAME`
```

Есть ли в sql такая возможность сделать вложенный запрос с подстановкой значений в поле dir (если содержится 1 то подставить "да" иначе "нет")?

Comment: Поле `dir`, получаемое как результат выполнения функции `ORD()`, имеет числовой тип. Что тогда должно означать "содержится 1"? Присутствие цифры 1 в десятичном представлении числа? Если да, то тупо ``CASE WHEN ord(substr(t2.`LOGDATA`,5,1)) LIKE '%1%' THEN 'да' ELSE 'нет' END``.

Comment: Спасибо что откликнулись. По долгу работы пришлось составлять запрос с которым вообще никогда не сталкивался. Это я сочинил за 3 часа но застрял на подстановке. А не могли бы вы ткнуть пальцем куда этот CASE вставить а то я уже настолько запутался что уже не пойму ничего...

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Огромное спасибо [Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina) за готовое решение!

```
select 
    t1.`ID`,
    t1.`TABID`,
    t1.`NAME`,
    t3.`NAME` as device_name,
    t2.`LOGTIME`,
    -- ord(substr(t2.`LOGDATA`,5,1)) as dir
    CASE WHEN ord(substr(t2.`LOGDATA`,5,1)) LIKE '%1%' THEN 'да' ELSE 'нет' end as dir
from
    `tc-db-main`.personal as t1
inner join 
    `tc-db-log`.logs as t2
inner join 
    `tc-db-main`.devices as t3
on
    t1.`ID` = t2.`EMPHINT`
and 
    t3.`ID` = t2.`DEVHINT`
and 
    logtime 
between 
    '2019-12-02 07:00:00' and '2019-12-02 23:00:00'
order by `NAME`
```